# JavaScript: Store Object as Fixed Value?

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I've noticed this behavior when writing my JavaScript, and I haven't been able to figure out why:

Below is some code to reproduce the behavior in question.

```
var o1 = {
  num: 1
}
var o2 = o1;
o2.num = 2;
alert(o1.num);
```

**Expected Result:** The browser alerts 1, because I only changed a property of the *o2* object, not the *o1* object.

**Actual Result:** The browser alerts 2, because it seems *o1* is equal to *o2*.

I'm not really sure what's going on. How can I fix the code so it alerts 1 rather that 2 (assuming that *o1* hasn't changed)?

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: "o2" became reference of "o1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because both variables **reference** *the same* object. Objects are not cloned/copied on variable assignment. [*You would have to do this yourself*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object).

JavaScript behaves the same way like any (most) other OO languages in this case.

Answer (score 3):

By writing `var o2 = o1;` you're making `o1` and `o2` two references to **the same object**. What you want to do is to **clone** the `o1` object and to store the **cloned copy** in `o2`. Search for cloning objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are setting the objects to the same reference point.  You need to clone the object.  here is a piece of code from http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2008/04/10/javascript-cloning-objects/ that allows for cloning of objects with prototyping.

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
  return eval(uneval(this));
}
alert("test".clone());
alert((3).clone());
alert(clone.clone());
```

Comment: Remember that uneval() is available only on Firefox. It doesn't work on IE, Chrome and Safari as far as I know.